# upload staff leave field status database table (Lotus notes 8.5.3) to Human resources table (Oracle 9I)

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, lotus-notes, lotus, lotusscript

I'm using Oracle 10g Express or Oracle XE and lotus notes 8.5.3. In the Staff Leave Database i have few field need to update on last run of the leave database to oracle database.

example fields are :

```
StaffID,
StaffName,
LeaveTitle,
LvStartDate,
LvEndDate
```

to update to oracle database

```
EmplyID,
EmplyName,
Lv_Title,
Lv_Start_Date,
Lv_End_Date
```

Matching field from Leave DB to Oracle HR DB :

```
StaffID=EmplyID
StaffName=EmplyName
LeaveTitle=Lv_Title
LvStartDate=Lv_Start_Date
LvEndDate=Lv_Start_Date
```

Question 1 : 
Anyway to identify whether staff information is been modify or create new document
(Lotus database)?

Question 2 : 
What Lotus script / method to update on Oracle database.

Normally we update information is use "Replaceitemvalue"

```
**notesDocument.ReplaceItemValue( itemName$, value )**
```

It is using the same way to updating it?

Answer (score 1):

problem solve already.....my client oracle database dint set properly. That why give an error. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

For connecting to Oracle, I would look into the LSConnection classes and use those to update the tables in Oracle.  There are samples around the web but this gives the general idea:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/0/06354b64eb34aa92852572900060b3d3?OpenDocument

To determine if the information has been modified, a simple way to handle that is to write code in the QueryOpen and QuerySave events of the form.  Store the values of those fields in the QueryOpen event, and then check to see if they are modified during the QuerySave event.  If they are modified, just set another field to the current date/time to indicate it has been modified.  Then you can look for all modified documents since a certain date in your update script.

Comment: i understand the connection from lotusnotes to Oracle...but i dont understand which part of my Oracle code go wrong..below is my script.